# Why does C# explicitly implement parent interfaces for its built-in types?

Tags: c#, .net

From my understanding, given an interface **Interface Parent** and then an interface that inherits from Parent eg: **Interface Child : Parent**, the **Child** will automatically require the members of the Parent to be implemented without needing to specify such.

Yet I notice for all the built-in types that both **Parent** and **Child** are specified when implementing interfaces.
eg:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>...
```

Going off the above example of the built-in **List** type, why does it specifically implement **ICollection** for example when **IList** already does this? Why implement **IEnumerable** when **ICollection** already does this? Etc..

Is this the way things should be done generally or is there a specific reason this is done for the built-in types?

Comment: *where* are you looking at this information? Bear in mind that documentation or decompiled code may show interfaces that don't appear in the original source, for various reasons. According to [the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646), `List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>`  is the complete declaration.

Comment: (Also, bear in mind that `List<T>` *isn't* a "built-in type" of C#. It's a *.NET Framework* type)

Comment: yes, the decompilation is showing the implied/indirect interfaces as well as the explicit ones, for your convenience. it's redundant to list them again anyway and would have no effect.

Comment: That's not explicit implementation to begin with. The [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) shows all the implemented interfaces, it doesn't imply that the source looks that way. [There are some explicit implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#explicit-interface-implementations) but those are mainly the non-generic interfaces

Comment: You're exactly right this is as a result of the decompiler. Thanks! Question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation page for List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) shows all the interfaces implemented by the type, it doesn't imply that the source looks that way. In the [.NET Old source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,36) the signature is just:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>)
```

There are some [explicit implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#explicit-interface-implementations) but those are mainly the non-generic interfaces `IList` and `ICollection` that people really shouldn't be using without an explicit effort

Comment: The signature is the same for .NET Core: [source.dot.net](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/List.cs,22)